# Set background colour of custom Windows desktop

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop, windows-10-desktop

I have some POS-like application where the user is not allowed to access the underlying operating system. Thus I currently create an own desktop with CreateDesktop() which does not provide access to any operating system functions.

This works well but there is one problem with Windows 10: this desktop is black by default, causing some misunderstandings during load ("wow, the monitor is off?").

So my question: how can I set the background colour for such a desktop programmatically?

Comment: That's what the [single-app kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) is for.

Comment: @IInspectable not suitable for my application, as mentioned it is a POS-like-application, but not a real one - whole story is more complicated. That's why I have to go the hard way via Desktop-functions, and that's why I have to modify it programatically

Comment: Can't you just open a window on the new desktop and display whatever background you want?

Comment: Do you want to start the windows explorer shell for the desktop? Try to start a new instance of `C:\\Windows\\System32\\sihost.exe` in the target desktop, with [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), and set `STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop` to `"winsta0\\dew"`

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT no, there is no windows stuff and no explorer shell running on this new desktop, just one single application which offers some control element to the user absolutely exclusively.

Comment: You could try as @JonathanPotter said, create a window([Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe)) and set it `HWND_BOTTOM`(Places the window at the bottom of the Z order).